# Jquery popup when mailto link is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of code but it's not doing what I want.

Whenever someone clicks on a mailto link, a popup will display the following message 'This is the message.' So far nothing is happening

```
$('a[href^=mailto:]').click(function () { 
    var x=window.confirm('This is the message.');
    var val = false;
    if (x)
        val = true;
    else
        val = false;
    return val;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').click(function(){
    return confirm('This is the message.');
});
```

Comment: You don't **need** the quotes, quotes are always optional. You just need to escape the colon (or other special characters) as such: `$("a[href^=mailto\\:]");`. http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors#Special_characters_in_selectors

Comment: True. I think this is just the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes

```
  $('a[href^="mailto:"]')
```

And while we're at it how about just:

```
 var x=window.confirm('This is the message.');
 return x;
```

for the body of the function?